# How do you train Falxmen in Rome Total War?

Tags: rome-total-war

How do you get falxmen in Rome Total War? I have checked the building plans and I can't find them. I understand that you need to be Germania. Is it just a rare unit you can recruit like druids?

Comment: [Falxmen are Dacian units](http://totalwar.wikia.com/wiki/Falxmen_%28Dacia%29), not Germanian, and [Dacia is a non-playable faction](http://totalwar.wikia.com/wiki/Dacia), so no.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Actually they also belong to Thrace, another non-playable faction.

Comment: There is a mod that allows you to play unplayable factions. Thrace was always my favorite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to play as any faction by changing the `descr_stat.txt` file. However, this is not an official mod, so do this at your own risk.

[This website will be helpful](http://rtw.heavengames.com/rtw/mods/tutorials/descr_strat/index.shtml) (if you're not confident in changing game files I wouldn't do it).

This will tell you how to change all the factions in the game into playable (all but rebels, as rebels = slave), even the main Roman Senate faction. Playing as Rebels/slaves or Roman Senate is buggy so not recommended for regular play.

> The `descr_strat.txt` file can be found in the `data\world\maps\campaign\imperial_campaign` folder[...] [the below] section determines which factions are playable[...] To change this, simply cut and paste them into another section.

The section of `descr_strat.txt` you're looking for looks like this:

```
playable    
  romans_julii
  romans_brutii
  romans_scipii
end 
  unlockable    
  egypt
  seleucid
  carthage
  parthia
  gauls
  germans
  britons
  greek_cities
end 
nonplayable 
  romans_senate
  macedon
  pontus
  armenia
  dacia
  numidia
  scythia
  spain
  thrace
  slave
end
```

---

Bonus tip: You can look in the building browser of cities you do not control to see the units/buildings for that faction.